# why check is undefined in my code? 'pure js'

Tags: javascript

** I want when to click on the active button if the checkbox is checked to add filtered class in HTML element but it doesn't work and give me an undefined error in this line *check.parentElement.classList.add("filtered");* **

```
        <ul class="ul-list"></ul>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
      <button class="all footer-btn">All</button>
      <button class="active footer-btn">Active</button>
      <button class="complete footer-btn">Complete</button>
    </footer>

let check = document.querySelectorAll(".complete-txt");
let complete_btn = document.querySelector(".complete");
let active_btn = document.querySelector(".active");
let all_btn = document.querySelector(".all");
let edit_list = document.querySelector(".edit-list");
let main_text = document.querySelector(".main-text");
let list_item = document.querySelector(".list-item");
let footer = document.querySelector(".footer");

const generateTemplate = (todo) => {
  const html = `
  <li class="list-item">
  <input type="checkbox" class="complete-txt"  name="" id="check"><span class="main-text">${todo}</span><div class="edit-list"></div><div class="delete-list"></div>
</li>
  `;
  list.innerHTML += html;
};

// add todos event
addForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const todo = addForm.add.value.trim();

  if (todo.length) {
    generateTemplate(todo);
    addForm.reset();
  }
});

active_btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let check_id = document.querySelector(".complete-txt");
  // check.forEach(function () {
  debugger;
  if (check.checked !== "true") {
    check.parentElement.classList.add("filtered");
    console.log("hi");
  }
  // });
  // console.log("hi");
  console.log("hi");
  // console.log(check.checked.value);
});
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll(".complete-txt")` returns a NodeList, that list doesn't have `parentElement`, the error fires when you're trying to refer `classList` of `undefined`.

Comment: i use querySelector (".complete-txt") or getElementById but doesnt working

Comment: there are multiple errors, the "check" is defined before creation of the DOM, for the active_btn onclick you're defining "check_id" but are using the aforementioned undefined "check". you're also adding the checkbox to "list" which you have not defined

Answer (score 0):

if the larger document fixes all other inconcistencies you should be able to change the eventlistener to

```
active_btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let check_id = document.querySelector(".complete-txt");

  
  if (check_id.checked !== "true") {
    check_id.parentElement.classList.add("filtered");
  }
});
```

BUT!!! this will not "fix" all of your errors, like defining `let check` before the checkbox is created with `generateTemplate`